# C++ Initialize Member Array with Constructor Argument

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I have a template class that contains a single member array of compile-time constant length.  I want this array to be constant, but initializing it based on constructor-provided input is proving difficult:

```
struct Input {
    int value;
};

template<size_t Size>
struct Foo {
    int const myVals[Size];
    Foo(std::array<Input, Size> const &in)
        : myVals{ in[0].value, in[1].value, /* How many times? */ } {
    }
}
```

Since I don't know the size of the array, I don't know how many values with which to initialize `myVals`.  The following code works, but I question whether it is the best approach:

```
template<size_t Size>
struct Foo {
    std::array<int, Size> const myVals;
    Foo(std::array<Input, Size> const &in)
        : myVals{ toIntArray(in) } {
    }
private:
    static std::array<int, Size> toIntArray(std::array<Input, Size> const &in) {
        std::array<int, Size> result;
        for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < Size; ++i) {
            result[i] = in[i].value;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Is there a more succinct, or generally more accepted way to populate the values of a constant member array?

Comment: @JeJo When I try that in VS2017u2, I get one of three errors (one when `myVals` has type `int[]`, one when initializing with `myVals{in}`, and finally, one when initializing with `myVals(in)`).  Which compiler are you using where an `std::array` can be initialized by a type with different template parameters?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about that. That won't work. However, the way you followed is good.(IMHO) That should be also done by some template magic though. ;). *Unpack the std::array<Input, Size>* -> *cast to int, if needed* -> *make tuple of elements* -> *move to member array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::index_sequence` to get the indices of the array as a non-type template parameter pack. Then you can use a parameter pack expansion.

```
template<size_t Size>
struct Foo {
    int const myVals[Size];
    Foo(std::array<Input, Size> const &in)
        : Foo(in, std::make_index_sequence<Size>()) { }
    private:
    template<size_t... Is>
    Foo(std::array<Input, Size> const &in, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : myVals{in[Is].value...} { }
}
```

Using a helper template with a `size_t... Is` pack and a `std::index_sequence<Is...>` argument is a common pattern for handling fixed-size indexable containers. The `index_sequence` doesn't actually do anything; it's just a proxy so that the `Is` template arguments can be deduced. E.g. if you [check on Godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Astruct+Input+%7B%0A++++int+value%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Csize_t+Size%3E%0Astruct+Foo+%7B%0A++++int+const+myVals%5BSize%5D%3B%0A++++Foo(std::array%3CInput,+Size%3E+const+%26in)%0A++++++++:+Foo(in,+std::make_index_sequence%3CSize%3E())+%7B+%7D%0A++++private:%0A++++template%3Csize_t...+Is%3E%0A++++Foo(std::array%3CInput,+Size%3E+const+%26in,+std::index_sequence%3CIs...%3E)%0A++++++++:+myVals%7Bin%5BIs%5D.value...%7D+%7B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++Foo%3C2%3E+f(std::array%3CInput,+2%3E%7B%7B%7B1%7D,+%7B2%7D%7D%7D)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.29831006612784,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang800,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.0749542399999998,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-Wall+-O1',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+8.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.70168993387216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) it appears to totally evaporate under `-O1`.