# Initialize member array with constructor argument (with plain old arrays)

Tags: c++, c++17

Very similar to this: [C++ Initialize Member Array with Constructor Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908503/c-initialize-member-array-with-constructor-argument)
But I don't use `std::array`, or rather, really rather not use it if there are other options.

I have this class (simplified):

```
template<typename T, int length> // Line 53
class StaticArray
{
    public:
        T items[length];
        StaticArray() = default;
        StaticArray(T newItems[length]) : items{newItems} { }
};

int main()
{
    StaticArray<int, 4> a;                                       // Works (uninitialized)
    StaticArray<int, 4> b = StaticArray<int, 4>();               // Works (initialized to 0)
    //StaticArray<int, 4> c = StaticArray<int, 4>({});           // Does not compile
    //StaticArray<int, 4> d = StaticArray<int, 4>({1, 2, 3, 4}); // Does not compile
    //StaticArray<int, 4> e = {1};                               // Does not compile
    return 0;
}
```

The lines with `a` and `b` work fine. But `c` does not compile:

```
....main.cpp:59: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
....main.cpp:66:51:   required from here
....main.cpp:59:49: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
   59 |         StaticArray(T newItems[length]) : items{newItems} { }
      |                                                 ^~~~~~~~
      |                                                 |
      |                                                 int*
```

Neither does `d`:

```
no matching function for call to ‘StaticArray<int, 4>::StaticArray(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
....main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
no matching function for call to ‘StaticArray<int, 4>::StaticArray(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   67 |     StaticArray<int, 4> d = StaticArray<int, 4>({1, 2, 3, 4});
      |                                                             ^
....main.cpp:59:9: note: candidate: ‘StaticArray<T, length>::StaticArray(T*) [with T = int; int length = 4]’
   59 |         StaticArray(T newItems[length]) : items{newItems} { }
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
....main.cpp:59:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int*’
   59 |         StaticArray(T newItems[length]) : items{newItems} { }
      |                     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
....main.cpp:58:9: note: candidate: ‘StaticArray<T, length>::StaticArray() [with T = int; int length = 4]’
   58 |         StaticArray() = default;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
....main.cpp:58:9: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
....main.cpp:54:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr StaticArray<int, 4>::StaticArray(const StaticArray<int, 4>&)’
   54 | class StaticArray
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
....main.cpp:54:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const StaticArray<int, 4>&’
....main.cpp:54:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr StaticArray<int, 4>::StaticArray(StaticArray<int, 4>&&)’
....main.cpp:54:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘StaticArray<int, 4>&&’
```

`e` doesn't because `StaticArray` is not an "aggregate type".

I don't understand the intricacies of C++ well enough to know what's going on here. I do understand that given `int a[4]; int b[4];` you can't simply do `a = b;`. But replacing `items{newItems}` in the constructor with `items{1, 2, 3, 4}` works fine, **and so does `items{{1, 2, 3, 4}}`**!
I suspect that the whole argument type decay thing is screwing this up.
I can remove all constructors entirely and have `e` work, but that then allows initialization with lists that are not of the proper size, which is quite silly.

Any pointers to workarounds? I would really rather not faff about with template magic or `std::array`-like kajiggery. The "purer" the better.

Comment: why don't you want to use `std::array` ? It solves most issues with c arrays, for example you cannot copy a c-array as a whole

Comment: your "the purer the better" concerns are a little misplaced. `std::array` is nothing more than what you need to avoid the issues that c-arrays have

Comment: I don't see how your implementation could be any "purer" than std::array

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn how to use std::array. Also, templates are not magic, they are a basic part of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This constructor:

```
template<typename... TNewItems>
StaticArray(TNewItems... newItems)
: items{newItems...}
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(newItems) == length, "Number of supplied items must match the length of the array.");
}
```

Use like this:

```
  StaticArray<int, 4> a;                                     // Works (uninitialized for int, calls the default constructor for complex types)
  StaticArray<int, 4> b = StaticArray<int, 4>();             // Works (0, 0, 0, 0)
  StaticArray<int, 4> c = StaticArray<int, 4>({});           // Weirdly works (0, 0, 0, 0; does not call the custom constructor)
  StaticArray<int, 4> d = StaticArray<int, 4>({1, 2, 3, 4}); // Works (1, 2, 3, 4)
  StaticArray<int, 4> e =                     {1, 2, 3, 4};  // Works (1, 2, 3, 4)
//StaticArray<int, 4> f = StaticArray<int, 4>({1, 2});       // Fails to compile
//StaticArray<int, 4> g =                     {1, 2};        // Fails to compile
```

The template-magic is reasonably minimal. Error messages for wong types (as far as C++ catches wrong types in general) in the initializer list are quite legible, even for templated classes.
The `static_assert` allows checking for an incorrect number of items. The error message in case of a mismatch is very legible.
The empty initializer list causing everything to be initializd to 0 is a bit weird, but not too bad.